# Deep copying is affecting both the arrays

Tags: javascript, object

I'm having two objects(say obj1 and obj2) If I change  obj1 it is affecting in obj2 also. I'm trying to change the multiple['w']=10. Is there any way for copying object without affecting in second object i.e obj2

```js
let obj1={ 
  "director":{
    "data":[
      "multiple":{
        "w":1
      }
     ]
   }
}

let obj2={...a}
```

Comment: `{...a}` makes a shallow copy - it will only take the first level of the object properties. And since they are objects themselves, you get references to the same objects.